# .animate() function not working (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I've just started studying JQuery and I can't get this code working. I think it's OK but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">

    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="button1">Animar 1</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="box"></div>

</div><!--Container-->
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).on("ready",main);

function main(){
    $("#button1").on("click", animate1);
}

function animate1(){
    $("#box").animate({
        width: '100px'
    });
}
```

*Edit: I added the CSS code too, so you can also check this. I don't really know if it's necessary but here it is.*

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background: #4674A5;
}
#container{
    margin:100px auto;
    width:500px;
}
#caja{
    background: #FF8000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
#menu{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
    color:white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu li:hover{
    color:#FF8000;
}
```

Comment: Please always consider to set a descriptive title relevant to your question...

Comment: Please consider editing your title to something more relevant to the question. `"My JQuery code doesn't work"` isn't helpful to anyone else.

Comment: please also always add a jsfiddle

Comment: Other than the fact that `#box` is invisible without any styles, [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/jAx5L/1/) seems to be working fine… can you explain what exactly is not working..?

Comment: Sorry, I already edited the title to a more specific one. My english isn't so good, but I'll try to explain myself. The thing is that I've used JQuery before to animate the scroll bar so the page could move. But I can't get any code working now. I've tried all of you guys codes and none of them works for me. Everything is nicely vinculated and all ID attributes match. I haven't downloaded any JQuery framework, but I don't think this is the problem since I've been able to use it before. What can it be?

Comment: @RofhMichaels BUT are you including jQuery??? Any error in console? Replicate issue online, don't let people just wondering...

Comment: @A.Wolff OK now it gave me this message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Comment: @RofhMichaels This is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Yjk65/  As you see, once set some content in DIV #box and set overflow property, your code works (even you shouldn't use `on('ready',handler)` syntax)

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks a lot. But why does it work on JSFiddle and not on my computer? (I copied the exact same code)

Comment: @RofhMichaels Again, check your console for error. It could be many many things and i don't know what you are doing...

Comment: What @A.Wolff said. It seems you are not including jQ at your end. The *"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"* points to that.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   main();
   function main(){
      $("#button1").on("click", animate1);
   }

   function animate1(){
      $("#box").animate({
         width: '100px'
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: @KingofPopup's because you can bind pseudo ready event using on(), but this won't take advantage of internal deferred object used to fire pseudo event even once already fired

Comment: I think what @KingofPopup's is trying to say is that the Op's code is at least working as is. The problem lies elsewhere. The `.on` problem in his view is secondary.

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, honestly i didn't get you. i [tried this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/jAx5L/) upon seeing the question and the function is firing on load. So my question is - how does this answer fixes OP's not working code..? what exactly is not working in it..?

Comment: @KingofPopup's I meant, using on(), then this won't work (wrapped inside onload method): http://jsfiddle.net/jAx5L/3/  It could be or not OP's issue here, depending context how/when his posted snippet is called. OP would have better to improve his question for sure